# How to plot very high odds ratios in R using forestplot? (Issue with max limit on clip)

Tags: r, clip, r-forestplot

I have been trying to display the odds of receiving a psychotropic medication for a list of psychiatric diagnoses but have not been able to show the entire range (on a log scale) due to the limitations of the x axis.

Looking at the forestplot documentation, it appears that the clip() is what is used to specify the xlimits. However, I have noticed that anytime I set it to be something greater than 54 the number on the bottom will not be shown at all and it stops at 4. This is an issue for me because I need to plot numbers as high as 221 (the upper confidence limit for my highest odds ratio).

I am using the following code:

```
# Cochrane data from the 'rmeta'-package
base_data <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(19.92 , 41.46, 11.67, 11.69, 25.44, 105.89, 145.45),
                            lower = c(17.09, 34.70, 9.04, 10.92, 19.78, 67.40, 95.64),
                            upper = c(23.22, 49.54, 15.07, 12.51, 32.73, 166.37, 221.22),
                            study = c("Autism", "Conduct Problems", "Tic Disorder", "ADHD",
                                      "OCD", "Schizophrenia", "Manic Bipolar"),
                            OR = c("19.92" , "41.46", "11.67", "11.69", "25.44", "105.89", "145.45"))

base_data |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, OR),
             clip = c(0.1, 54),
             xlog = TRUE) |>
  fp_set_style(box = "royalblue",
               line = "darkblue",
               summary = "royalblue") |> 
  fp_add_header(study = c("", "Study"),
                OR = c("", "OR")) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = 60.22,
                lower = 41,
                upper = 83,
                study = "Summary",
                OR = "60.22",
                is.summary = TRUE) |> 
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF")
```

Which creates this graph:

[image]

If I set the clip to 220 I am able to plot this but the x axis will stop at 4 as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get past this issue and set the xlimit ticks to a very high number (e.g. 100+) while still using a log scale?

Keeping it on a log scale would mean there would be an equal distance between 1, 10, 100, and show the entire range of answers (up till the final value of 221)while still allowing one to see the difference between values at the lower end.

Any help is extremely appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forestplot/versions/3.1.1/topics/forestplot):

> xlog: The xlog outputs the axis in log() format but the input data
> should be in antilog/exp format

So you could change your data using `exp`. To add labels you can use `xticks`. Here some reproducible code:

```r
library(forestplot)

base_data$mean <- exp(base_data$mean)
base_data$lower <- exp(base_data$lower)
base_data$upper <- exp(base_data$upper)
base_data |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, OR),
             xlog = TRUE,
             xticks = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250))|>
  fp_set_style(box = "royalblue",
               line = "darkblue",
               summary = "royalblue") |> 
  fp_add_header(study = c("", "Study"),
                OR = c("", "OR")) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = 60.22,
                lower = 41,
                upper = 83,
                study = "Summary",
                OR = "60.22",
                is.summary = TRUE) |> 
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so for sending this! I am wondering, do you know if it is possible to show all of the values while keeping it on a log scale? Meaning that there would still be an equal distance between 1, 10, 100, etc. ?